# Can I share CoreData on iCloud?

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I have an iPhone app I'm writing that needs to keep an offline data store that users of a specific licensed app can access.

I need a "Cloud" account where several users with different accounts can share the data.  Is this possible?

I Googled and searched SO, but can find nothing about this particular topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An iCloud account is tied to a single user.

If you are asking whether you can set up an iCloud account that can be shared across multiple users; there isn't such a thing.

If you don't want to be responsible for syncing and vending the data yourself, have a look at Dropbox - where users can set up shared dropbox folders to do something similar to what you are asking about.

However, just putting the CD store on a Dropbox folder won't be enough to handle merge conflicts if different users modify the same value. In which case one solution is to have a web service that updates can be sent to, merges resolved, and the data pushed back down to the devices to be stored in their own Core Data stores.

A bit more involved than just putting the store in the cloud - but this stuff is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

you need to start off with icloud

one of the best tutorials on net is:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6031/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2

sample icloud project
http://cdn3.raywenderlich.com/downloads/dox.zip

best of luck

Comment: Hi Sam... I have read the first article... let me make sure I understand it:  I CAN share a document (CoreData?) between devices; that being said, each different group of users would have to sign up for an iCloud account, where the app could create the data store.  Is this correct?

Comment: Hi Sam... I got further clarification from the customer so I modified the question.

Comment: The question is about sharing an iCloud account between users, your answer doesn't address this.